# Unverified Breakpoint in VS Code for API written in Express

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the debugging of VS Code and it appears to be somewhat working. While setting a breakpoint in a file just works fine, in other files it's not the case.

[image: That's how it looks]

Even though the both files are under the same path (api/services/...), the result is different.

How can i set breakpoints anywhere I want ?